# In jQuery: How To Get (Natural) Width Of Created IMG

Tags: jquery, image

I have this code:

```
var img = $('<img>')
.attr('src','a.jpg')
.load(function(){
    alert(img.width()) ;
}) ;
```

Width is always equal to 0,

How to get natural width size?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I just *console.log(img)* then I saw *naturalWidth*,
but only way to get it is: *img[0].naturalWidth*

http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/L9dMD/1/

Comment: Change the source after the load function is attached, and use `.on('load', function() {});` as `load()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is right.

```
var img = $('<img>')
.attr('src','a.jpg')

// Correct till here
// Wrong after this!

.load(function(){
    alert(img.width()) ;
});
```

But, still it is not in the DOM as a layout. So, this won't work. What you need to do is, you need to place it in the DOM.

So, the best thing is, laying it inside the DOM and get the property.

```
var img = $('<img>')
.attr('src','a.jpg')
.appendTo('body');
alert(img.height());
img.remove();
```

---

#### Updated working fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('<img>')
        .attr('src','http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/rich-tehrani/uploads/new-microsoft-logo.png')
        .css('visibility', 'hidden')
        .appendTo('body');
    var imgHt = img.height();
    alert(imgHt);
    img.remove();
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/KpCRe/

Comment: So you mean, create img with "document.createElement('img')"?

Comment: Hey... Wait. I got a fiddle.

Comment: @Digerkam Check now... :) The same thing.

Comment: FYI for the first run in the fiddle i get 0 width. On refreshing I get the width - as the image is now cached.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yea, it was wrong. That's why I gave an updated solution. Check the second one.

Comment: Do I have to append element to DOM? I want to do some canvas action, I dont want to show original image :(

Comment: Yeah, giving `css('visibility', 'hidden')` will not show it. :)

Comment: does not have to be in DOM and won't get dimensions until it is loaded which is why fiddle is faling